# combining DT::datatable, proxy and selectizeInput field in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm programming a shiny app which should provide a list of all the selected entries in a `DT` `datatable`. I want to be able to **unselect** a single entry in the `datatable` without going through the whole table and unselecting all entries.

What I did was using the development version of `DT` and the proxy connection. With this I can select rows in my text field which automatically selects the rows in the `datatable` and vice versa.

Problem occurs if I select "to fast". So if I delete like 10 entries in the text field very quickly, the whole thing updates it again and seems to hang in an endless loop updating itself.

Is there any way to use semaphores or something similar to prevent this behaviour? It gets more extrem since I am creating figures with `ggplot2` in my original app which takes a second or more depending on the number of rows you select in the `datatable`.

I also provide the a button to unselect all the the rows, but I want to be able to unselect a specific row.

Here is a reproducible example with some sample data. It is not doing anything. So just select a few rows and remove them fast from the textfield to see what I am talking about.

```
library(shiny)
# devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT') # Needs developmentversion for proxy
library(DT)

annotation <- data.frame(
  names=sapply(seq(1000), function(x) paste0(sample(letters,5, replace=FALSE), collapse='')),
  values=runif(1000)
)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         selectizeInput('selected_names', 'selected name',
                        width='100%',
                        unique(annotation$names),
                        multiple=TRUE)
      ),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   ),
   DT::dataTableOutput("my_table")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(annotation)
  })
  proxy = DT::dataTableProxy('my_table')

  shiny::observe(
    {
      rows <- match(input$selected_names, annotation$names)
      print(rows)
      selectRows(proxy, as.numeric(rows))
    })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    selected_rows <- input$my_table_rows_selected
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'selected_names',
                         selected=annotation[as.numeric(selected_rows),]$names)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You can probably add another button and have Shiny only updates the table and plot when the button is clicked. This will require one more click from the user though.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Hmmm, I am guessing it is related to this issue: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1181 because the problem arises when you call `selectRows` too close together.

Comment: Hm, yeah sound very similar. Actually I thought about the button idea from @warmoverflow which makes the whole thing much easier I guess. @Carl thanks for pointing me to `options(shiny.trace=TRUE)` within that link. This will help a lot in the future! :-)